# Ogre3d / Compositor related issue

Tags: c++, directx, shader, ogre, cg

I killed my whole day trying to figure out, why the code below is not working:

I have this .compositor script:

```
compositor BW
{
    technique
    {
        texture rt0 target_width target_height PF_A8R8G8B8

        target rt0
        {
            input previous
        }

        target_output
        {
            input none

            pass render_quad
            {
                material BlackAndWhite
                input 0 scene
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.material script:

```
vertex_program BW_VP cg
{
    source MyShader.cg
    entry_point BW_VP
    profiles vs_4_0 vs_2_0 vs_1_1 arbvp1

    default_params
    {
        param_named_auto worldViewProj worldviewproj_matrix
    }
}

fragment_program BW_FP cg
{
    source MyShader.cg
    entry_point BW_FP
    profiles ps_4_0 ps_2_0 arbfp1
}

material BlackAndWhite
{
    technique
    {
        vertex_program_ref BW_VP{}
        fragment_program_ref BW_FP{}

        texture_unit
        {
            texture rt0
            tex_coord_set 0
            tex_address_mode clamp
            filtering none
        }
    }
}
```

and a .cg program:

```
sampler2D RT : register(s0);

void BW_VP(in float4 inPos : POSITION, out float4 pos : POSITION, out float2 uv0 : TEXCOORD0, uniform float4x4 worldViewProj)
{
    pos = mul(worldViewProj, inPos);
    inPos.xy = sign(inPos.xy);
    uv0 = (float2(inPos.x, -inPos.y) + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
}

float4 BW_FP(float4 pos : POSITION, float2 iTexCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR
{
    float3 greyscale = dot(tex2D(RT, iTexCoord).rgb, float3(0.3, 0.59, 0.11));
    return float4(greyscale, 1.0);
}
```

I use statements below to initialize compositor:

```
Ogre::CompositorManager::getSingleton().addCompositor(mViewport, "BW");
Ogre::CompositorManager::getSingleton().setCompositorEnabled(mViewport, "BW", true);
```

And i see no results at all. I have couple of lights and cg shaders in my scene - they work perfectly well. Also, all resources are loaded properly, and the resource group sees every needed file, however i get this exception in the log file:

```
OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource rt0 in resource group Mission 1 : Deliver Tom or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at D:\ARCHIVES\DEPENDENCIES\OGRE_REPOSITORY\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
```

AFAIK rt0 shouldnt be a resource due to its automatic generation "on flight" by ogre. Am i missing something?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception error is *correct*: you haven't a texture file resource with that name, however OGRE will create a blank texture for you.

However I see two problems:

1. In compositor file what is *scene*? Instead of **scene** you must use **rt0**, this is the render target where your scene is rendered and where you go to apply the material.
2. The lack of *pass* statement in the material script.

Comment: You're right! But somehow even after this change the compositor is not working!

Comment: Also, i changed 'texture rt0' to 'content_type compositor BW rt0' But that didnt make any difference! Its still not working

Comment: I've noticed just now an inadvertence in the material script: where is the _pass_ statement? I've tried your code (adding the pass statement) and it works properly.